# Gutenberg/WordPress - Limit number of categories

Tags: block-editor

I would like to limit the number of categories chosen (3 max) in the categories list of WordPress.

But **Gutenberg** interface use **React** and my jQuery code don't work.

Can I have some help please ?

```
jQuery(window).load(function() {
    var limit = 3;

    $('.edit-post-sidebar input.components-checkbox-control__input').on('change', function(evt) {
        if($(this).siblings(':checked').length >= limit) {
            this.checked = false;
        }
    });
});
```

I found this part of code in `components.js` file of WordPress :

```
function CheckboxControl(_ref) {
  var label = _ref.label,
      className = _ref.className,
      heading = _ref.heading,
      checked = _ref.checked,
      help = _ref.help,
      onChange = _ref.onChange,
      props = Object(objectWithoutProperties["a" /* default */])(_ref, ["label", "className", "heading", "checked", "help", "onChange"]);

  var instanceId = Object(external_this_wp_compose_["useInstanceId"])(CheckboxControl);
  var id = "inspector-checkbox-control-".concat(instanceId);

  var onChangeValue = function onChangeValue(event) {
    return onChange(event.target.checked);
  };

  return Object(external_this_wp_element_["createElement"])(base_control, {
    label: heading,
    id: id,
    help: help,
    className: className
  }, Object(external_this_wp_element_["createElement"])("span", {
    className: "components-checkbox-control__input-container"
  }, Object(external_this_wp_element_["createElement"])("input", Object(esm_extends["a" /* default */])({
    id: id,
    className: "components-checkbox-control__input",
    type: "checkbox",
    value: "1",
    onChange: onChangeValue,
    checked: checked,
    "aria-describedby": !!help ? id + '__help' : undefined
  }, props)), checked ? Object(external_this_wp_element_["createElement"])(build_module_icon["a" /* default */], {
    icon: check["a" /* default */],
    className: "components-checkbox-control__checked",
    role: "presentation"
  }) : null), Object(external_this_wp_element_["createElement"])("label", {
    className: "components-checkbox-control__label",
    htmlFor: id
  }, label));
}
```

[image]

Comment: Your solution in the first code block approaches this from a DOM manipulation standpoint, but Gutenberg doesn't look at the checkboxes to see which categories are selected. Instead, it's data driven. Checking and unchecking a box changes the data store, and when the data store changes, the entire checkbox list is thrown away and recreated based on what the data says. It's the data you need to focus on, the data creates the UI. So look into WP Data, you should not need to look at or modify UI controls

Comment: Thank you. How can I look into WP Data ? wp.data.select( 'core/post' ) ? 
With which select ? And where exactly please ?

Comment: Those are good questions I do not have answers to at hand, I was just leaving a comment to be helpful, else I'd have written an answer